# Why doesn't Close() closes the form in the load event?

Tags: .net, winforms

In my load event on a form, I call some method in a try catch block. When an Exception occurs, I show the user a message and after that I want to close the form. It looks like this (code in Load event):

```
try
{
   Metehod();
}
catch(DatabaseException ex)
{
  MessageBox.show("db error! " + ex.Message);
  this.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Unknown error!" + ex.Message);
  this.Close();
}
```

But, when `this.CLose()` is called, it doesn't close the form, no, the code keeps running till the end of the load event!

Why is this? Is this logical behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is logical behaviour. Calling Close() does not return control to the caller. The method will continue execution unless you tell it otherwise. Putting a `return` after each `this.Close()` does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

It's by design because `Load` [occurs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242139(VS.60).aspx) **before** a form is displayed for the first time. So `Close()` has no effect since three events later in the `Form` [life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242139(VS.60).aspx), the form is shown.

To stop the cycle, use devnull solution.